# Read two textfile line by line simultaneously -java

Tags: java, io, text-files, readfile

I have 2 textfiles in two different languages and they are aligned line by line. I.e. the first line in the textfile1 should be equals to the first line in textfile2, and so on and so forth.

Is there a way to read both file line-by-line simultaneously?

Below is a sample of how the files should look like, imagine the number of lines per file is  around 1,000,000.

textfile1:

```
This is a the first line in English
This is a the 2nd line in English
This is a the third line in English
```

textfile2:

```
C'est la première ligne en Français
C'est la deuxième ligne en Français
C'est la troisième ligne en Français
```

desired output

```
This is a the first line in English\tC'est la première ligne en Français
This is a the 2nd line in English\tC'est la deuxième ligne en Français
This is a the third line in English\tC'est la troisième ligne en Français
```

Currently, i can use this but saving a few million lines in the RAM will kill my machine.

```
String english = "/home/path-to-file/english";
String french = "/home/path-to-file/french";
BufferedReader enBr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(english));
BufferedReader frBr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(french));

ArrayList<String> enFile = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = enBr.readLine()) != null) {
    enFile.add(line);
}

int index = 0;
while ((line = frBr.readLine()) != null) {
    String enSentence = enFile.get(index);
    System.out.println(line + "\t" + enSentence);
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Why not combine the two reads into a single while loop?

Comment: I'd say that given two 1,000,000 line files that the chance that they're both EXACTLY aligned for all 1,000,000 lines is pretty slim. Your code is going to be brittle unless you can work around that fact.

Comment: Do you have to print the lines only or also have to store them?

Comment: May be it could be useful for you one day, but, if you are working on an Unix system, consider using this command : `paste -d '\t' english french > englishandfrench`

Comment: i've to store them and most probably index them into a textfile immediately after reading each sentence from two files.

Comment: How many different ways are there to read in a text file.  I have used scanner and the new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile)); but I am sure there are different ways. I found that even with the Scanner object there are at least three different ways. I would post them up but I am at work right now and do not have access to my computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the calls to `nextLine` on both readers in the same loop:

```
String english = "/home/path-to-file/english";
String french = "/home/path-to-file/french";
BufferedReader enBr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(english));
BufferedReader frBr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(french));

while (true) {
    String partOne = enBr.readLine();
    String partTwo = frBr.readLine();

    if (partOne == null || partTwo == null)
        break;

    System.out.println(partOne + "\t" + partTwo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks now it works, i think the `index` will be useful in counting the number of sentences. But i've used `if(...)continue;` instead of `break;`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader enBr = ...
BufferedReader frBr = ...

String english = "";
String french = "";
while (((english = enBr.readline()) != null) && ((french = frBr.readline) != null))
{
    strings.add(english + "\t" + french);
}
```

Comment: But if the french file contains more lines, those lines won't be part of the result.

Comment: @Zakaria: If that is true then I think that this statement does not hold: `I have 2 textfiles in two different languages and they are aligned line by line. I.e. the first line in the textfile1 should be equals to the first line in textfile2, and so on and so forth.`

Comment: =) this method works too, but the other method is more intuitive without the global `String english` , `String french`. This solution will be more apt if i have to compare to the previous sentnece to see whether it is the same.

Comment: @npinti : IMHO, the "should be" part has to be implemented by handling non-conform files (ex:different number of lines) :)

Comment: What if there are multiple files ?

Comment: @plzdontkillme: There should be 2 files.