# Reading two text files line by line simultaneously

Tags: python, file, io, readfile

I have two text files in two different languages and they are aligned line by line. I.e. the first line in textfile1 corresponds to the first line in textfile2, and so on and so forth.

Is there a way to read both file line-by-line simultaneously?

Below is a sample of how the files should look like, imagine the number of lines per file is  around 1,000,000.

textfile1:

```
This is a the first line in English
This is a the 2nd line in English
This is a the third line in English
```

textfile2:

```
C'est la première ligne en Français
C'est la deuxième ligne en Français
C'est la troisième ligne en Français
```

desired output

```
This is a the first line in English\tC'est la première ligne en Français
This is a the 2nd line in English\tC'est la deuxième ligne en Français
This is a the third line in English\tC'est la troisième ligne en Français
```

There is a Java version of this [Read two textfile line by line simultaneously -java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831007/read-two-textfile-line-by-line-simultaneously-java), but Python doesn't use bufferedreader that reads line by line. So how would it be done?

Comment: This is not Python, but if you just need the output in a new file, `paste textfile1 textfile2 > output` should work too.

Comment: If you like larsmans' answer, you might want to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
    with open("textfile1") as textfile1, open("textfile2") as textfile2: 
        for x, y in izip(textfile1, textfile2):
            x = x.strip()
            y = y.strip()
            print(f"{x}\t{y}")
```

In Python 2, replace built-in `zip` with `itertools.izip`:

```
    from itertools import izip

    with open("textfile1") as textfile1, open("textfile2") as textfile2: 
        for x, y in izip(textfile1, textfile2):
            x = x.strip()
            y = y.strip()
            print("{0}\t{1}".format(x, y))
```

Comment: I get the issue:  
 File "MergeANNOVARResults.py", line 10
    with open(refseq) as refseq_fh, open(gencode) as gencode_fh:
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Would this load all of textfile1 and textfile2 to memory?

Answer (score 26):

```
with open(file1) as f1, open(fil2) as f2:
  for x, y in zip(f1, f2):
     print("{0}\t{1}".format(x.strip(), y.strip()))
```

**output:**

```
This is a the first line in English C'est la première ligne en Français
This is a the 2nd line in English   C'est la deuxième ligne en Français
This is a the third line in English C'est la troisième ligne en Français
```

Comment: Be aware that zip() will pull the full contents of both files into memory (in Python 2.x)

Comment: Better use [`from itertools import izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) or [`izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

Answer (score 6):

We could use `generator` for more convenient file opening, and it could easily support to iterator on more files simultaneously.

```py
filenames = ['textfile1', 'textfile2']

def gen_line(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip()

gens = [gen_line(n) for n in filenames]

for file1_line, file2_line in zip(*gens):
    print("\t".join([file1_line, file2_line]))
```

**Note:**

1. This is `python 3` code. For `python 2`, use `itertools.izip` like other people said.
2. `zip` would stop after the shortest file is iterated over, use `itertools.zip_longest` if it matters.

Answer (score 4):

Python does let you read line by line, and it's even the default behaviour - you just iterate over the file like would iterate over a list.

wrt/ iterating over two iterables at once, itertools.izip is your friend:

```
from itertools import izip
fileA = open("/path/to/file1")
fileB = open("/path/to/file2")
for lineA, lineB in izip(fileA, fileB):
    print "%s\t%s" % (lineA.rstrip(), lineB.rstrip())
```