# Preferred way of iterating over two files line by line in python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.6

In `Python 2.7` and later, one can use a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295171/read-two-textfile-line-by-line-simultaneously-python) to iterate over two files line by line. However, in earlier versions of Python this doesn't work and gives an *invalid syntax* error.

I was wondering about the best way to do this using `Python 2.6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way is still the same only, but `with` statement doesn't support multiple objects in a single statement. So, you might want to split it like this

```
from itertools import izip

with open("Input1.txt") as textfile1: 
    with open("Input2.txt") as textfile2:
        for x, y in izip(textfile1, textfile2):
```

According to the [PEP-0343](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), "Specification: The 'with' Statement" section,

> A new statement is proposed with the syntax:
>
> ```
>    with EXPR as VAR:
>        BLOCK
> ```
>
> Here, `with` and `as` are new keywords; EXPR is an arbitrary
>       expression (but not an expression-list) and VAR is a single
>       assignment target.  It can *not* be a comma-separated sequence of
>       variables, but it *can* be a *parenthesized* comma-separated
>       sequence of variables.  (This restriction makes a future extension
>       possible of the syntax to have multiple comma-separated resources,
>       each with its own optional as-clause.)