# Read lines from Multiple files

Tags: python, readlines

I have two files:

A:

```
John
Kevin
Richard
```

B:

```
Manager
Salesperson
Doctor
```

I am trying to read lines from both the files simultaneously and print the following:

Output:

```
John is a Manager
Kevin is a Salesperson
Richard is a Doctor
```

I tried using contextlib.izip package but it's not working.

Code:

```
with open('name') as names:
        with open('job') as jobs:
                for names1 in names:
                        jobs1 = jobs.readlines()
                        print names1 + jobs1
```

But this throws error as

```
`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`
```

I also tried using contextlib package but it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read two textfile line by line simultaneously -python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295171/read-two-textfile-line-by-line-simultaneously-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) function, and multiple context managers:

```
with open('name') as name_file, open('job') as job_file:

    for name_line, job_line in zip(name_file, job_file):

        print("{} is a {}".format(
            name_line.strip(), job_line)) # don't forget to strip the newline 
                                          # from the names
```

This code will work for Python 3. If you are working in Python 2, use [itertools.izip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip).

The other solutions posted here that utilize `readlines()` work, but they use an unnecessary amount of memory. There is no need to read in two whole files when all you care about is a single pair of lines at a time, so I would strongly recommend the iterator approach I have described here instead.

Comment: nice! i didn't know one could use multiple contexts like this. Very concise!

Answer (score 0):

You basically want this:

```
# These can come from open("file").readlines()
a = ("John", "Kevin", "Richard")
b = ("Manager", "Salesperson", "Doctor")

for person, role in zip(a, b):
    print("{} is a {}".format(person, role))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the two files separately and then zip the results

i.e.

```
with open('name') as f:
    name = f.readlines()

with open('job') as f:
    job = f.readlines()

roles = zip(name, job)
```

Or, you can use a nested loop as you show in your code. the problem is in `readlines()`, which will return all lines read. However, a file object is a generator in python, so you can iterate over it simply.

```
with open('name') as names:
    with open('job') as jobs:
        for n in names:
            for j in jobs:
                print("{n} is a {j}".format(n=n, j=j))
```

I prefer the first option because its more readable.