# Comparing 2 text files

Tags: python

I have 2 text files I wants to compare column 3 and 4 t only if column 1 and 2 is the same in the files .

Text 1 :

```
12345,67890,4.6,5.7
89736,62828,5.1,4.2
63793,38392,5.4,7.3
```

Text 2:

```
12345,67890,4.6,5.7
63793,38392,5.4,7.3
```

My code :

```
pre = open ("g.txt","r")
post = open ("g2.utm","r")
line = pre.readlines()
if not line:                                                
   break                                                     
if line.startswith("L"):
    print ("\n")         #to avoid the header
else :    
    v = line[0:5]                                      
    l = line[6:11]                                      
    i = line[12:14]
    k = line[15:17]
line2 = post.readlines()
if not line2:                                                
   break                                                     
if line2.startswith("L"):
    print ("\n")         #to avoid the header
else :    
    v2 = line[0:5]                                      
    l2 = line[6:11]                                      
    i2 = line[12:14]
    k2 = line[15:17]
    if v == v2 and l == l2 :
        d = (i - i2)
        h = (k - k2)
        if d >= 6.25 and h >=6.25:
            print (v2,l2,"not ok")

print ("Done")
```

Comment: plz clarify your question. add some example input and output

Comment: What is the expected output? A function always needs some kind of output...

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: Sorry for that .. know it's updated

Comment: will this values always be 5 digit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is too much repetitive and messy. Let me suggest you some modification in your code. First read the file line by line. How could you do that?

```
with open("g.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a_line_of_the_file = line
```

Next, instead of accessing the values with index, you can split them with commas and save them to a list.

```
valuelist = a_line_of_the_file.split(',') 
# contains ["12345","67890","4.6","5.7"] at first iteration.
```

When you have two list from each row of two files, you can always compare them by index like:

```
if valuelist1[0]== valueList2[0]:
    do_something
```

Cast the value first if you need another datatype.

You should now solve your problem yourselves. If you still got error, plz inform.

Comment: For simultaneous access to files, you can see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295171/read-two-textfile-line-by-line-simultaneously-python