# Python For loop repeats second loop

Tags: python, regex, loops, for-loop

I have 2 files (a.txt and shell.txt)

in a.txt there are 59 lines and I've extracted their domains with the regex

in shell.txt there are 5881 lines.

The domains from a.txt exists in shell.txt and I want to extract the entire line of shell.txt if the domain of a.txt exists in shell.txt

Unfortunately my loops are not working right so I would like to get some help from you guys.

Thanks.

```
import re

s1 = open('a.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
s2 = open('shell.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()


for x in s1:

    c1 = re.findall("\/\/(.*)\/",x.split("|")[0])[0]

    for x2 in s2:

        c2 = re.findall("\/\/(.*)\/",x2.split("|")[2])

        if c1 == c2:

            print x2
```

Comment: In what way are they not right?

Comment: @SirParselot is not working, I can't get the x2 codes + if I print c1 inside the c2 for loop c1 will repeate 3 million times.

Comment: `c2` is list but `c1` is not..it should give an error

Comment: If I print c2 in the second loop, the lines are printed 346.000+ times:

root@ubuntu:~/links# python a.py  > wat
root@ubuntu:~/links# wc -l wat
346979 wat
root@ubuntu:~/links#

Comment: You are getting exactly what you're supposed to if you print c2. `59*5881=346979`.  It would help if you gave us a sample of your files

Comment: @rock321987 it shouldn't give an error but they will never be equal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read two textfile line by line simultaneously -python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295171/read-two-textfile-line-by-line-simultaneously-python)

Comment: @SirParselot The domains from a.txt exists in shell.txt and I want to extract the entire line of shell.txt if the domain of a.txt exists in shell.txt

Comment: That's not a sample, that's an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try not to do a loop with regex on the inside. Instead grab as much as you can directly from `s1` and `s2` (without `splitlines()`) with `findall`. The resulting `c1` and `c2` should be list.

To find intersection between the two list, I'd just use sets:

```
intersects = set(c1).intersection(set(c2))
for intersect in intersects:
    print intersect
```

If you need help on constructing the regex you need, I 
will need to know more about the files and what you are trying to extract.

Edit:

For the regexes, this might work:

```
regex1 = r"^[^|]*\/\/([^|]*)\/"
c1 = re.findall(regex1, s1, re.M)
regex2 = r"^[^|]*(?:\|[^|]*){2}\/\/([^|]*)\/"
c2 = re.findall(regex2 s2, re.M)
```