# Unknown column in where clause when updating database

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to add info into a record from two different files, I'm trying to achieve this by opening the first file and adding to a record, then opening the second and updating that record.

```
with open('C:/Users/ELITEBOOK/documents/github/chatbot/chatbot/bot/human_text.txt', 'r') as table2, open('C:/Users/ELITEBOOK/documents/github/chatbot/chatbot/bot/robo_text.txt','r') as table3:
        for line in table2.readlines():
            message_text = line
            #for robo_line in table3.readlines():
            message_intent = ''
            message_entities = ''
            test = 'hello'
            #cursor.execute('START TRANSACTION')
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO conversation (text) VALUES ('%s')" % line)
            cnx.commit()
            #cursor.execute((line))
            for robo_line in table3.readlines():
                #message_reply = robo_line  
                cursor.execute("UPDATE conversation SET reply = '%s' WHERE text = %s " % (robo_line, line)) 
                #cursor.execute(robo_line)
                cnx.commit()
```

I am receiving a `Unknown column 'start' in 'where clause'` error, "start" is just the string from the first line in my second text file. I'm using string formatters right now because otherwise I get a syntax error, this code is only being used to update the DB once, not in production.

Comment: Your `for` loop keeps updating the same rows of the table with different replies. Is that really what you want?

Comment: No I dont want that lol, I want to update different rows, the rows that have the proper text to correspond with the proper reply. I've been struggling with this the whole day Doe each record have an id automatically or do you mean I should make one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the value, since it's a string, just like you did for the string you're setting `reply` to.

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE conversation SET reply = '%s' WHERE text = '%s' " % (robo_line, line))
```

But it would be better to use a prepared statement rather than string formatting, to prevent SQL injection. Then you don't put quotes around placeholders, `cursor.execute` replaces them safely.

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE conversation SET reply = %s WHERE text = %s ", (robo_line, line))
```

Also, your looping is wrong. You don't want to loop through the entire `table3` for every line in `table2`, you just want to read both files in parallel. See [Read two textfile line by line simultaneously -python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295171/read-two-textfile-line-by-line-simultaneously-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
with open('C:/Users/ELITEBOOK/documents/github/chatbot/chatbot/bot/human_text.txt', 'r') as table2, open('C:/Users/ELITEBOOK/documents/github/chatbot/chatbot/bot/robo_text.txt','r') as table3:
    for line, robo_line in zip(table2, table3):
        message_text = line
        message_intent = ''
        message_entities = ''
        test = 'hello'
        #cursor.execute('START TRANSACTION')
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO conversation (text, reply) VALUES (%s, %s)", (line, robo_line))
        cnx.commit()
```

Comment: Okay, do I not need to use quotes around the value in the second example?

Comment: Correct, read the documentation of `cursor.execute()` to see how it does parameter replacements.

Comment: Okay thanks, but this is giving me another problem now. I'm literally getting `%s` inserted into my database under my "text" column

Comment: The `text` column is just in the `WHERE` clause, this code can't modify it. It only modifies the `reply` column.

Comment: Did you also change the `INSERT` line? If you got rid of the format operator, you have to remove the quotes.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the proper way to loop through the two files.

Comment: You probably also want to do `line = line.strip()` and `robo_line = robo_line.strip()` to remove the newlines before you put them into the DB.

Comment: ahh thank you for this, it was one of those problems where i didn't even know the question I was asking. The best I could come up with was "How do I insert into a record from multiple files?"