# How to init dictionary only with keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to initialize a dictionary in python when I only have the keys and not the values - The values will come later in the code.

I thought about to do something like this:

```
dict = {}
for key in key_list:
    dict[key] = None
```

The question is if this is a good practice for this problem or do you have a better recommendation?

Comment: but why though?

Comment: Because the keys are initialized from one file and the values come from another file. And each line in the inputs file has another value. I want to have the dictionary before I read the values

Comment: just store the "keys" in a list or something? or read both files at once and make the dict as you go

Comment: I suspect something like `keys = read_data(file_one); values = read_data(file_two); d = dict(zip(keys, values))` might be better

Comment: @SuperStew I can't read both of them at once

Comment: @ShakedEyal sure you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295171/reading-two-text-files-line-by-line-simultaneously

Comment: @SuperStew I know you can do it, but it is not in the requirements of the program. I need to read them separately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the `fromkeys` method:

```py
# As noted in comments, fromkeys is a staticmethod on the dict class and will return a dict instance
d = dict.fromkeys(list(range(10)))

d
{0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None}
```

To more directly address the point:

```py
list_of_keys = ['o1', 'o2']

d = dict.fromkeys(list_of_keys)
{'o1': None, 'o2': None}
```

Comment: No need to create the list, `fromkeys` will iterate on its own, and there is no need to create `d` since `fromkeys` is a staticmethod. `dict.fromkeys(range(10))`

Comment: @DeepSpace I left it as a `list` to be directly applicable to what OP is asking for, *can I create a dict from a list of keys*, rather than could it be created from any iterable

Comment: And if I have specific keys and not numbers? for example, I have something like this: `{'o1': None, 'o2': None}`

Comment: @ShakedEyal it would take the same structure: `dict.fromkeys(['o1', 'o2', ...])`

Comment: @C.Nivs But OP already has a list, so a better example (if we follow your argument) would be `dict.fromkeys(key_list)`

Comment: @DeepSpace true, I've added in a more direct example

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If your keys are already in memory, assuming an iterable object, then:

```
d = {key:None for key in keys}
```

It is the same as your posted code, just condensed.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

You can try that class method.